# Eclipse Runnable Jar Export Not Launching

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, lwjgl, slick2d

I am currently working on a game in Java and tried to export my first release as a runnable jar.

As Eclipse has a tool for this, I tried to use it.

After trying many different ways, I could still not launch the game. I made sure to export as a runnable jar and added the library.

My suspicions are as follows: The game's project is set up like this: `src->package->code, Res->images` and so on, JRE System Library, and finally referenced `libraries->Slick2d`, `lwjgl`, and `jinput`.

As it happens, I could find no way to get the jar to replicate the workspace folder organization. I believe that is what is causing it to crash; the required files are in unknown paths to the program.

I then tried to reorganize the files myself, only to be told that the jar is corrupted.

If anyone could please help by telling me what the issue may be, how to fix it, or any tips what-so-ever, I would be very thankful!

Comment: can u please lets know abt  what is happening on launching the jar ? Verify the referenced libraries are there in jar, also check the class path that the libraries are added to cp .

Answer (score 0):

Use JarSplice to include the library, your jar and the natives in 1 jar.
It didn't work because natives and slick jars were missing.

Answer (score 0):

eclipse comes with the option to package the required Jar along with the main Jar. [image]